# Distance between cluster center and outliers in R

Tags: r, cluster-analysis

I’ve build a cluster model with R (based on kmeans) and would like to classify the outliers by finding the minimum distance between the outliers and the center of the cluster. The Dataframes I'll like to use look like this:

DF_OUTLIERS

```
[Product]  [Sales] [Usage]
1   100 1000   
2   200 2000  
3   300 3000  
4   200 4000   
5   100 5000
```

DF_CLUSTER

```
[Cluster] [Center_Sales] [Center_Usage]
1    120        1500  
2    220        2400 
3    150        3900    
4    140        4900
```

The target table should look like this:

```
[Product]   [Sales]     [Usage]     [Cluster] 
1       100     1000        ???
2       200     2000        ???
3       300     3000        ???
4       200     4000        ???
5       100     5000        ???
```

To calculate the distance I want to use the standard formula for Euclidean distance:

```
sqrt((Sales -  Center_Sales)^2 + (Usage -  Center_Usage)^2))
```

My biggest problem is to develop a function which find the minimum of all clusters for every row without adding a new column for every cluster to the target df. I guess for an experienced programmer it is an easy task but I’am an absolute beginner with R and have no idea how to solve this problem.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Could you publish some data using `dput(your_data)` or some fake data similar to your?

Comment: I've generate some fake data. How can I add files to my post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a convenient `which.min` function that is useful in this situation.

```
outliers<-read.table(header=TRUE, text="Product  Sales Usage
1   100 1000   
2   200 2000  
3   300 3000  
4   200 4000   
5   100 5000")

clusters<-read.table(header=TRUE, text="Cluster Center_Sales Center_Usage
1    120        1500  
2    220        2400 
3    150        3900    
4    140        4900")

answer<-sapply(1:nrow(outliers), function(x) {
  #find the distance for the outlier to every cluster
  distance<-sqrt((outliers$Sales[x] -  clusters$Center_Sales)^2 + 
                   (outliers$Usage[x] -  clusters$Center_Usage)^2)
  #find the index of the shortest distance and return
  which.min(distance)
})

answer
#[1] 1 2 2 3 4
outliers$cluster<-answer
```

As long as the number of outliers and clusters are reasonable, one should have good performance.

Comment: this function is exactly what I am looking for. Thanks!